# Spring Dynamic Validation

Tags: java, spring, validation

I am new to Spring validations. Previously i have used Struts validations. For dynamic validations, we will configure in errormessages.properties file like "errors.required={0} is required." later we will replace {0} with name. Is ther anyway in spring also for doing this. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bellow code snippet may help you.

errormessages.properties

```
 errors.required={0} is required
```

you need to define ResourceBundleMessageSource bean in spring-context.xml.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframwork.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"> 
    <property name="messages">
         <list>
           <value>errormessages</value>
         <list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In bean messageSource Member variable to access messages.

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;
```

Second argument is array of object to pass.

```
messageSource.getMessage("errors.required",new Object[]{"Name"},"Default Required Error Message",null);
```

Comment: what is the property name "messages"..is it list of messages files names..in your snippet you mentioned value as errormessages as it is the name of the file..So can i include some more property files there...where should i store the errormessages file..how it is different from basenames variable..In your

Answer (score 2):

If you are implementing Spring Validator interface ( http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validator) - you can directly specify message arguments using

```
 void reject(String errorCode, Object[] errorArgs, String defaultMessage);
```